# System Settings in Spotlight in Sonoma

Tags: shortcut, spotlight, sonoma

We can use Spotlight to bring up the Bluetooth on/off toggle, for instance.

**How does one toggle the setting without using a mouse?**

[image]

https://www.macrumors.com/guide/50-new-macos-sonoma-features/#37._system_settings_in_spotlight

Comment: I would guess that Apple makes it hard to turn off crucial settings using just voice control through Siri.

Comment: "Siri, turn off/on Bluetooth" works for me.